# Development license for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, licensing

We are a software company developing a system using Google Maps for our customer internal use (commercial, with GPS device). I know that our customer need to have Google Maps premier license.

My question is: Does my company need to pay Google any license fee for development purposes?

Comment: That's a question you should ask Google.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / terms of use / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2):

(IANAL and I don't speak for Google)

I would definitely check with Google and/or get your own lawyer's opinion, but the bolded section below would make me think that you would not need a premier license for the development phase.

[Maps API TOS](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html)

> 9.1 Free, Public Accessibility to Your Maps API Implementation. Your Maps API
>   Implementation must be generally
>   accessible to users without charge.
>   You may require users to log in to
>   your Maps API Implementation if you do
>   not require users to pay a fee. Unless
>   you have entered into a separate
>   written agreement with Google or
>   obtained Google's written permission,
>   your Maps API Implementation must not:
>
> (a) require a fee-based subscription
>   or other fee-based restricted access;
>   or (b) operate only behind a firewall
>   or only on an internal network
>   ***(except during the development and testing phase)***.

Comment: Nov 2013: We just have been contacted by Google Europe and were told that selling a Maps API Implementation to a customer requires a OEM License. This is regardless wether you charge a one time fee or a recurrent fee. This is regardless if you operate the Maps API Implementation on your own server or on the customers server. This was new to me.

Comment: I should have added, that I cannot find any passages in the TOS that support this position by sales/3rd party companies. Otherwise it seems that a website without api-key (from the cloud console) is treated as "development key".